# Easy one condition statement file info

Tags: php, symfony, conditional-statements, content-type, fileinfo

i didnt found a good answer on the web..

I'm using symfony2.5 and php 5.3 and creating a file explorer application.

I want to know the extension of the file before apply the good associated content-type.
 mime_content_type function is deprecated..

Here is my showAction{} , i need a function who test if the file is an excel one or a pdf file :

```
public function showAction($repertoire, $file)
{

    $response = new Response();
    $response->setContent(file_get_contents(''.$repertoire.'/'.$file.''));

    if(file_info($file) == 'application/pdf'){

    $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/pdf');
    $response->headers->set('Content-disposition', 'filename='. $file);
    return $response;

    }else {

    $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/application/vnd.ms-excel');
    $response->headers->set('Content-disposition', 'filename='. $file);
    return $response;
    }
}
```

I'm starting with programming. Can you help me guys ?
Thanks a lot !

Comment: You must return the response object.

Comment: my condition doesnt work, post edited

Comment: why don't you test the file extension?

Comment: application/pdf  without quotes ? It can't work, you should have syntax erros.

Comment: i need help to create my function / condition  guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`finfo` is a little strange. You have to create a `finfo` resource, then use that resource to inspect a file, like so:

```
$finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
if('application/pdf' === finfo_file($finfo, $file)) {
    ...
}
```

or, the OOP way:

```
$finfo = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
if('application/pdf' === $finfo->file($file)) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: 1) Call to undefined function 'finfo_open'   and  2) Class 'finfo' not found

Comment: I've activated php_fileinfo.dll extension in my php.ini AND IT WORKS GREAT ! Thanks @hair raisin